# Exact Differential equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, linear-pde

We call any differential equation of the form $$M(x, y)\,\mathrm{d}x + N(x, y)\,\mathrm{d}y = 0$$  an 'exact differential equation' when $$M_y= N_x.$$

It appears that the following differential equation is **not** exact,
$$(2x + y)\,\mathrm{d}x - (x + 6y)\,\mathrm{d}y = 0$$ because $ M_y = 1 \ne -1 = N_x$.
But my friend is insisting that this an 'exact differential equation'. Comment please.

Comment: I would agree with you. Your friend doesn't appear to be using the definition.

Comment: Just as a sidenote, the more commonly accepted terminology for your "exact equation" is perhaps "total differential".

Answer (score 1):

It is not exact; if your friend insists it is, tell them to show you the potential function.

The equation,  on the other hand, is homogenous. You have
$$
y'=\frac {2x+y}{x+6y}=\frac  {2+y/x}{1+6y/x} .
$$